# Can I connect more then 4 machines to 4 port SAS disk array?

Tags: sas, storage

I want to buy SAS (both host and disk interface) disk array with 4 SAS wide host ports. I'd like to connect to the array 1 server (preferably using 2 ports, separate HBAs and multipathing), but additionally also 4-5 rack workstations. Is it possible to connect more machines than the number of SAS ports? If so - how? What other hardware is needed?

Answer (score 1):

SAS Switches do exist. HP has one for the BladeSystem, and I found mention of one from Rancho.

http://rancho.com/

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah, we're looking into HP MSA2000sa G2 so I had seen info on the switches.